# C# LDAP query fails sometimes

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have this piece of code in a program, to query what groups a Windows-domain user belongs to.

```
    public void GetGroupNames(string userName, List<string> result)
    {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            UserPrincipal uPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName);
            if (uPrincipal != null)
            {
                PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> srcList = uPrincipal.GetGroups();
                foreach (Principal item in srcList)
                {
                    result.Add(item.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I just implemented it and was debugging it,

```
UserPrincipal uPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName);
```

always got null.
I then had to close visual studio to do something else. When I came back, opened up visual studio, this code just worked. A few days ago, there was a network problem in the organisation, I did not switch off my PC during that period. After the network went back to normal, I could connect to internet OK, I could remote desktop to servers etc, which proves that Active Directory authentication was done all right, but the above piece of code failed to find UserPrinical for a given name, e.g. my own. I then reboot the PC, the code worked fine. I am quite puzzled regarding this matter. Is anyone able to provide a good explanation for this??

Comment: Is this fault still happening? If you where to try this now, would you get an error?

Comment: @Derek No, this fault has not happened again, but, well, the network has been fine, too. This error only happens very rarely, without obvious reason. There's no error message. The outcome is simply that I got a null obj.

Answer (score 0):

UserPrincipal has some known bugs with in cross domain scenarios.  When it happens again, look and see if you can resolve groups from your machine. I have also encountered problems when unresolvable SIDs where group members.